# What is the radius of the neutron?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model, neutrons

I am trying to get a straight forward answer to the question of the experimental radius of the neutron. Codata group gives magnetic radius of about  0.84fm, while the negative mean square charge radius is around -0.11fm2. in various texts.  Now, apart from the quantum mechanical effects,  can such information be translated to an answer to the question of the radius of the neutron?

Comment: Unless you define, what is supposed to happen/change at this radius, it'll be hard to formulate a precise value. In an empty universe, the radius could be very big, because the wave function will be still high compared to even further out. That is why people use standard definitions, like those you cited

Comment: A neutron is not a tiny hard sphere. It's a tiny bundle of interacting quarks, which are themselves (probably) point particles. What's the radius of three dogs playing? There's certainly a distance to their combined center of mass within which you're very likely to bump into a dog before long, but does a probability of dog-bumping count as a radius? And if so, exactly which arbitrary magnitude of probability counts?

Comment: Thanks for comments, but you can define the radius of the proton as equal to its charge radius, codata group gives 0.875fm, using electron scattering (or electron spectroscopy) because the proton is positively charged. Quantum effects exist and the particle quantum mechanically spreads probabilistically all over the space, but still we can speak about the size of the atom, and the size of the proton and the distance of the electron cloud form the center of the nucleus..etc. So, can we say something similar for the radius of the neutron. Wikipedia  gives 0.8fm without credible reference.

Comment: Note that the same particle may have a different “radius” in different contexts. You quote the proton charge radius as “the” radius of the proton. However, the density of nuclear matter generally implies a larger radius, 1.2 fm or so. Nuclear matter also implies relatively similar radii for both charge states of the nucleon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are plain unfair in your "without credible reference" for WP. Argue why you believe the text cited is not credible (!?). I don't agree with its number, but I suspect they argue in a broad handwaving manner. The reason you are having trouble getting a "straightforward" answer is because the "radius" of a hadron is a mental construct, inferred by judicious/twisted interpretation of data: normally Fourier transforms of the momentum dependence of scattering data.

From these, you are trying to extract a notional picture of the size of a swarm of bees, In Feynman's favorite imagery.

The easiest/cheapest estimate for what you are after is not the charge radius, since the neutral neutron has the positive quarks concentrated in the center of the hadron, and the negative ones are on the outside, on average, hence the negative rms radius. You are probably looking for something like the confinement radius, which is similar for most hadrons, and you really don't want to start bothering lattice simulators about that. So, for *decades*, people consider the Compton wavelength of the particle, which for the neutron is ~ 1.31959 fm.

What you want to monitor is how the quarks, of all charges, are distributed in the swarm, so, of course, you'll go to articles like G A Miller's  *Charge Densities of the Neutron and Proton*
[Phys Rev Lett **99** (2007) 112001](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.112001), from which I reproduce a few radial profiles:

[image: charge density distributions]

[image: quark distributions]

You may observe that beyond one fermi, the neutron charge has stabilized to zero, and the quark distributions have settled to a  very tiny value, consistent with "commuters" on the virtual pion cloud fuzzing up the confinement radius. This is probably the best you can do for a notional fantasy picture of the type you are seeking. For any concrete application of this to a specific process, you have to be thoughtful, as always...

Comment: Thanks Cosmas Zachos for your detailed answer, and for the reference. WP states the 'radius' of the neutron as if it is a physical fact and then cite the reference, this is non-credible way of referencing. If the nucleus can have a definite value for such a 'notional fantasy picture', and the same for the proton inside it, then most probably we can have this fantasy notion for the neutron inside the nucleus too, otherwise we can state that the neutron can have a larger radius than its atom. I think that current experimental apparatus is still short of giving us such a 'fantasy picture'.

Comment: Indeed, considerations of nuclear packing are the calculus of overlapping swarms, where you have to be very fussy and careful in defining things consistently. WP  strives for an introductory impression of things, a mental framework to hang one's questions; but, remember, there is no substitute for books, review articles, and papers.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't agree with your statement "This is probably the best you can do for a notional fantasy picture of the type you are seeking." because the expression 'fantasy' means that the question doesn't belong to physics. For me an answer should 1) accept the question, 2) give a reply yes or no not an analysis, 3) if the reply is positive then give your estimate or range of the possible radius of the proton.

Comment: Aw forget it... There *is* no radius of a hadron, unless you defined it, as the first comment invited you to declare... This site provides insights, not game-show tie-breakers...

Answer (score 0):

In an article published by ScienceDaily about two years ago, this was said:

> "One of the fundamental properties of nucleons is their size as determined by charge distribution. 'Inside, there are positive and negative charge regions which, when taken together, result in zero total charge for the neutron," explains Evgeny Epelbaum.' The neutron's radius can be thought of as the spatial extension of the charge distribution. It thus determines the size of the neutrons."

Since we know it's nearly impossible to measure the position or size of a particle, Schrödinger's wave equations show us that it's more practical to measure them according to mass/charge density. A team of researchers from Institute of Theoretical Physics at Ruhr-Universität Bochum (RUB) has taken another *indirect* approach, which sadly, is about all we have until technology gets to the point where we can see neutrons.

But I do believe these guys have gotten the closest to an actual figure.

> "Our accurate prediction of the deuteron radius, combined with high-precision spectroscopic measurements of the deuteron-proton radius difference, yielded a value for the neutron radius that is about 1.7 standard deviations off the previous determinations," concludes Dr. Vadim Baru from the Helmholtz Institute for Radiation and Nuclear Physics at the University of Bonn. Accordingly, the previously assumed value for the size of a neutron is to be corrected.

Cheers.